# How to make laterjs working on top of sailsjs

Tags: javascript, sails.js, laterjs

I am trying to implement laterjs on top of sailsjs. In the bootstrap.js file, I add

```
sails.services.taskschedule.schedulepush();
```

before

```
cb();
```

and my "api/services/taskschedule.js" expose schedulepush() , I require 'later' in this file.
The problem is:

```
var schedule = later.parse.text('every 5 min');
var lt = later.setInterval(somfunction, schedule) ;
```

inside the schedulepush() is executed immediately and only once while I suppose it should run every 5 minutes.
Also,

```
console.log(lt);
```

is undefined.

What could the problem be? How can it be fixed?

Comment: The culprit is likely with the `someFunction` variable/callback--the rest appears fine

Comment: seems like a laterjs problem. I tried it with node-scheduler and it's working fine. I guess I'll use node-scheduler instead.